# Rust DList implements Deque?

Tags: rust, traits

[`collections::dlist::DList`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.11.0/collections/dlist/struct.DList.html) looks to implement [`collections::Deque`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.11.0/collections/trait.Deque.html), which has a `push_back` method.

But compiling this simple program:

```
extern crate collections;

fn main () {
    let mut c : collections::dlist::DList<int> = collections::dlist::DList::new();
    c.push_back(1);
}
```

gives this error messaage

```
try.rs:5:4: 5:16 error: type `collections::dlist::DList<int>` does not implement any method in scope named `push_back`
try.rs:5    c.push_back(1);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trait has to be imported for its methods to be available. This is also noted in the documentation:

> DList implements the trait Deque. It should be imported with `use collections::Deque`.

Comment: Yes.
BTW what is the reason of this requirement?

Comment: @Zoli Distinct traits can have methods of the same name. Considering only imported traits reduces the risk of collisions and gives a simple way disambiguate which one you want.